# if you invest $ 500 at 6 % compounded annually,

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Please help me with this problem. It needs to be done in the same format as below
if you invest $500$ dollars at $6$ percent compounded annually, how many years to the nearest tenth would it take your investment to grow to $\$1300$. MY answer was $16$.

please show solution and explain.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show how you got there? (As far as I can see, the solution "to the nearest tenth" should be $16.4$)

Comment: 1300=500(1.06)n then n=log(13)/log1.06

Comment: Try to solve 
$$
\text{target value} = \text{(initial value)}\cdot\left(1+\text{(compound interest})\right)^n
$$ for $n$. In what you just wrote, it should be $\ln\frac{13}{5}$ — the $5$ coming from the original $500$.

Comment: I need to do it there way... please

Comment: This *is* "their way". And it looks like this *is* what you just wrote above — but somehow you didn't round to $16.4$ but to $16$.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: the first 1 if you invest 500 dollars at 6 percent compounded annually, how many years to nearest tenth would it take you investemnt to grow to 1300

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer done "their" way-
We have $$1300=500(1.06)^n$$ $$\implies 13=5(1.06)^n$$ $$\implies \frac{13}{5}=(1.06)^n$$ $$\implies \log_{1.06}\frac{13}5 =n$$ $$\implies n \approx 16.39830702$$ $$\implies n \approx 16.4$$ Rounded to one decimal place.

Please ask if you need any further clarification.